# * gather argument in plt.scatter?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am reading [this](http://benalexkeen.com/k-means-clustering-in-python/) website and found this line of code:

```
for i in centroids.keys():
    plt.scatter(*centroids[i], color=colmap[i])
```

I understand `*` is used to gather an arbitrary length of arguments so we don't have to explicitly specify all the arguments, right?

But why does this person write the `*` here?

Especially since after removing the `*`, the line seem to produce the same result.

The complete code:

```
## Initialisation

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'x': [12, 20, 28, 18, 29, 33, 24, 45, 45, 52, 51, 52, 55, 53, 55,         61, 64, 69, 72],
    'y': [39, 36, 30, 52, 54, 46, 55, 59, 63, 70, 66, 63, 58, 23, 14,     8, 19, 7, 24]
})


np.random.seed(200)
k = 3
# centroids[i] = [x, y]
centroids = {
    i+1: [np.random.randint(0, 80), np.random.randint(0, 80)]
    for i in range(k) 
}

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5, 5))
plt.scatter(df['x'], df['y'], color='k')
colmap = {1: 'r', 2: 'g', 3: 'b'}
for i in centroids.keys():
    plt.scatter(*centroids[i], color=colmap[i])
plt.xlim(0, 80)
plt.ylim(0, 80)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Axes.scatter(x, y, ...)`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.scatter.html) takes two arguments x and y.

When removing the asterix you have one single argument only, hence `plt.scatter(centroids[i], color=colmap[i])` should throw a `TypeError: scatter() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)`.

The alternative would be to split the argument beforehands,

```
x,y = centroids[i]
plt.scatter(x,y, color=colmap[i])
```

Comment: I don't know why, but removing the * seems to work on my laptop, and the two graph look the same?

Comment: Also the 'for' loop is strange to me here, so the original code calls plt.scatter three times? Are there any differences between this version of code, and the alternative you have kindly provided?

Comment: No that would produce the same plot. And yes, your code calls scatter 4 times, once for all the black points, and then once per point in centroids.